# Producing multiple graph objects in igraph from lists of dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, igraph, mapply

I have two lists of around 80 dataframes- one for nodes and another for edges. I would like to use the igraph function graph_from_dataframe to join the nodes and edges dataframes make a single list of igraph objects. At the moment I have been trying this:

```
glst <- mapply(graph_from_data_frame, 
           d=ListOfEdgeDfs, 
           vertices=ListOfNodeDfs,
            SIMPLIFY = FALSE,
           directed =F)
```

However, this gives the error message:

```
Error in (function (d, directed = TRUE, vertices = NULL)  : 
  Some vertex names in edge list are not listed in vertex data frame
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works (for list of 2 graphs, the same should work for any number of graphs, can you make sure that the data frame structures are similar):

```
ListOfEdgeDfs <- list(data.frame(from=letters[1:3], to=c('b', 'c', 'd')), 
                      data.frame(from=rep('a',3), to=c('b', 'c', 'd')))
ListOfEdgeDfs
#[[1]]
#  from to
#1    a  b
#2    b  c
#3    c  d
#[[2]]
#  from to
#1    a  b
#2    a  c
#3    a  d

ListOfNodeDfs <- list(data.frame(node=letters[1:4]), data.frame(node=letters[1:4]))
ListOfNodeDfs
#[[1]]
#  node
#1    a
#2    b
#3    c
#4    d
#[[2]]
#  node
#1    a
#2    b
#3    c
#4    d

library(igraph)
glst <- mapply(graph_from_data_frame, 
               d=ListOfEdgeDfs, 
               vertices=ListOfNodeDfs,
               SIMPLIFY = FALSE,
               directed =F)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
#plot(glst[[1]])
#plot(glst[[2]])
```

**[EDITED]**

Try this:

```
n <- 2 # number of graphs
par(mfrow=c(2,1)) # if you have 100 graphs, try par(mfrow=c(10,10)) e.g.
invisible(sapply(1:n, function(i) plot(glst[[i]], vertex.size=50)))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Sandipan! Great! Do you know how I could change the code so that it plots all of the graphs in a single line of code? i.e. rather than writing plot(glst[[1]]), plot(glst[[2]])... plot(glst[[n]]) something that does it all in one line